# SonarQube MSBuild scanner: How to exclude C# files with fxcop issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

When excluding C# files in SonarQube, fxcop issues are still listed for these excluded files. We tried different ways to exclude the C# files, in the SonarQube server settings, but also in the ms project files, like this:

```
<Compile Include="test.cs">
  <SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>
</Compile>
```

Even though this file is clearly excluded, fxcop issues regarding the file are still listed. It somehow seems that SonarQube did not parse the information that the issues are connected to that file. The issues are listed in the proper module but without line numbers for the file, even though the raw output of the build contains the line number in the fxop issue.

Does anyone know how to properly exclude C# files in SonarQube, so that fxcop issues are also not listed?

Comment: Have you tried turning off fxcop rules in your SonarQube Quality Profile?

Comment: Well, we need the fxcop rules, we just want to exclude source files which are automatically generated, because we cannot fix issues in these files.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example where the FxCop output contains proper file and line location, and SonarQube is not importing the issue properly?

Comment: An example is:
`d:\Projekte\Model\test.cs(14): warning CA1819: Microsoft.Performance : Ändern Sie 'HINWEISLOG.LOG_ID' so, dass eine Auflistung zurückgegeben wird, oder erstellen Sie daraus eine Methode. [d:\Projekte\testproj.csproj]`

The path name is actually about 120 characters, I've shortened it here.

Comment: my report [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097875/exclude-list-not-working) I didn't know that FxCop was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue and can't provide any way to get rid of those FxCop issues. Here is our JIRA ticket for the issue, you can follow its progress: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-259

Comment: This issue has been moved here https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-fxcop/issues/1 but for us it remains unresolved. We installed sonar-fxcop on the server but it did not help at all. We are still getting hundreds of false positive issues. Is there any configuration steps that need to be done?